# Error in plot(net) : object 'net' not found

Tags: rstudio

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I am running the below code in Rstudio
`datas <- BNDataset("C:/Users/.../2.csv", "C:/Users/.../3.csv")`
`datase <- datas()`
`nets <- learn.dynamic.network(datase,num.time.steps = 2)`
`plot(nets)`
but it gives the erorr: Error in plot(net) : object 'net' not found
why it happens?

```
s <- cbind(c(0.017979678,   0.011345375 ,0.014793026,   0.010626496,    0.01597338, 0.012467991 ,0.01597338,    0.012725869,    0.011443908,    0.011985384
```

+ ),c(0.018303076,  0.011264264,    0.015559947,    0.01080083, 0.016515615,    0.012609419,0.016515615,    0.013153442 ,0.011887617,   0.012681979
+ ))

Comment: It's difficult to say without knowing your dataset. Edit your question with `dput(head(dataset))` and also tell us what package `learn.network` belongs to.

Comment: Flagging it as "needs clarity" meanwhile

Comment: ok, I edited it. I added the whole code that I'm running.

Comment: learn.network belongs to bnstruct package

Comment: I don't have files 2.csv or 3.csv (nor I'm willing to download them, in case anyone wondered), so please provide a small sample of your data

Comment: I added two pictures related to file 2.csv and 3.csv

Comment: Pictures? Please help us help you. Please make your question reproducible.

Comment: how can I add my data? I tried to copy paste, but it turns to a picture!

Comment: I added two rows of 2.csv with R code here

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say whether this is the problem, but with

```
datas <- BNDataset("C:/Users/.../2.csv", "C:/Users/.../3.csv")
```

you are creating a `BNDataset` object called `datas`, but

```
datase <- datas()
```

you are calling the function `datas` (which does not exist in `bnstruct`).